# Reactjs/handlebar : new page rendered is added at the end of first ,not replaced

Tags: html, reactjs, handlebars.js

I am new in Reactjs/handlebar and I'm working with my first project. I have a question that I think may be conceptual. I have the 'index' page with a navbar, when I click one option in the navbar I render a new page 'aboutus'. the problem is the partial {{>carrousel}} is always showing in the 'aboutus' page. thanks in advance.

```
router.get('/aboutus', (req, res) => {
  res.render('aboutus', {
      style: 'bootstrap.min.css'
  });
}


<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Navigation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Footer-Basic-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
</div>


    <body>

        {{>navigation}}
        {{>carrousel}}
       {{{ body }}}
    </body>
```

Comment: We can't help diagnose or fix code we can't see. Please share a [mcve] of the UI code rendering the routed content.

Comment: From what I see it is that `{{>carrousel}}` is unconditionally rendered. Is `{{>navigation}}` what is rendering the page content, i.e. an "about" page?

Answer (score -1):

see i am also new in react but if your are also new in react then my suggestion is to make first practice according to react rules like:-
past all nav, menu, about and all on App.js
**And main thing**  if you are using new v6 react then you have to use router in different way like Switch is not there you have to use Routes like:-

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Routes  } from "react-router-dom";



<Router>
<Navbar/>
<Alert/>
  <Routes>
   <Route exact path="/about" element={<About/>}/>
   <Route exact path="/" element={<TextForm/>}/>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).